# Cannot convert undefined value to object - React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, arraylist, iteration, react-native-sectionlist

I think I have some error in the SectionList, but I can't find any error, can you help me please?
[CoinDetailScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAjop.png)

I read the React Native documentation and I think I understand that I can't iterate the sections array, but I don't know how to apply it to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sections` instead of `section` property in the SectionList component.